# Can I sail my boat down the Thames?

Tags: united-kingdom

If I want to commute to work on my own boat, do I have to carry documents, special permits or whatever to sail down the River Thames?

Comment: Do you carry a driver's licence when you drive a car?

Comment: Where are you planning on docking your boat when you get to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to boat on any inland waterways in the UK you are required to have a boat registration (aka licence).

Unlike a driving licence there is no need to pass a competency-based assessment.

However, you must have a [boat safety scheme](https://www.boatsafetyscheme.org/) certificate (BSSC) and boat insurance (at least third party).

The Thames is overseen by the Environment Agency. [This page](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/river-thames-boat-registration-and-application-forms) on the Environment Agency website has a contact phone number for the registration team and links to the forms you may need.

Comment: You woulda passed a competency-based assessment if got the licence in some other country.

Comment: Note that this only applies to the non-tidal part of the Thames, i.e. upstream of Teddington Lock (roughly).  See https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/river-thames-boat-registration-requirements/river-thames-boat-regsitration-requirements-october-2016, third paragraph.  For the tidal portion (e.g. through central London), it appears the Port of London Authority is in charge.